# New Activity Page reputation section bug?

Tags: support, user-interface

My reputation section in the new Activity page started looking like this today:

[image]

All it shows is rep gained today from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961823/what-is-really-a-special-class), and not even all of it (10 points less than I got). All my other recent rep increases (latest was the day before yesterday) do not show.

The reputation tab itself is working properly.

This behaviour manifests across several devices and browsers both when logged in and logged out.

Is this a bug?

Comment: +1 Saw this in another user's reputation section too some days ago. I think it happens when you earn the daily maximum reputation.

Comment: @CoolGuy: but I'm 70 rep from the daily maximum! That can't be the reason!

Comment: Hmm, you're right. The reason is something else...

Comment: @CoolGuy: they are not capped yet. There are just a lot of reputation events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**: the following answer applied until March 2016. See footnote.

---

It shows the total for the most recent 24 events only; these add up to 113 points here (115 from 23 upvotes on the question, -2 from the one downvote). It'd also cap the events to a maximum amount of time passed, but since those 24 events are all today that doesn't apply here.

Yours is really an edge case as your most recent events are all applicable to just the one post; you have 28 events for that one question but the 4 oldest are not included in the total reputation change. Those 4 events make up the remaining 17 points you earned for the post.

---

Stack Overflow has stated the implementation is subject to change. Quoting Marc Gravell:

> Note: we're leaving the implementation details here as "subject to change"; the 24 events thing (which can actually also be 12 events, depending on what happens) is unreliable. We will probably play with this, and not worry too much if it changes what exact numbers get displayed (as long as it is all legitimate rep from somewhere)

Comment: Thanks, I never knew this was capped by anything but time!

Comment: Note: we're leaving the implementation details here as "subject to change"; the 24 events thing (which can actually also be 12 events, depending on what happens) is unreliable. We will probably play with this, and not worry too much if it changes what exact numbers get displayed (as long as it is all legitimate rep from somewhere)

Comment: @MarcGravell: thanks for the heads-up. Added that to the answer.