# Reputation bar chart summary malfunctioning

Tags: bug, status-completed

The post's area under reputation bar chart is not displaying more than 2 posts in [my case](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209018/rajaprabhu-aravindasamy?tab=topactivity).

[image]

Also I am not able to see the ***view more*** link. Is it a bug? If it is a feature, then why it is happening in my case?

**Edit:** Just now, I have received an upvote and that made the post's area to display 3 posts. But still I can see the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209018/rajaprabhu-aravindasamy?tab=topactivity).

**Edit:1**
The [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291913/1209018) which was linked by @coolguy is saying that basically the system would display the posts by consolidating the most recent 24 events. But in my case, at that time, 6 + 4 upvotes + 2 accepts, totally 12 events were displayed. Then what about the remaining 12 events? Yesterday I had [other events](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209018/rajaprabhu-aravindasamy?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2016-03-02%2019:28:53Z) too.

Comment: It is working for my SE profiles(verified SO, unix&linux) . [screenshot ref](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y6z9g.png), [my profile link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5832518/raju?tab=topactivity).

Comment: @CoolGuy The answer of your linked post is saying that basically the system would display the posts by consolidating the most recent 24 events. _It shows the total for the most recent 24 events only_ But in my case at that time, 6 + 4 upvotes + 2 accepts, totally 12 events. But what about the remaining 12 events?

Comment: ^^ I think then you should mention that in the question, so that people aren't confused if your question is a duplicate or not.

Comment: I'm reopening this because the duplicate suggestion is incorrect; there really is a bug here

Comment: An improvement to this should be available in the next build

Comment: @MarcGravell Thanks for your instant action against this bug. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, this is an ugly edge case. We actually do something evil here, to try to fill the grid. In your case, *because you got lots of votes only about 2 posts*, our hack failed to fully populate - essentially, we have a cheeky loop that can be summarized:

- we want to display `n` rows, so guess that we probably need to check at least `n*FACTOR` records
- fetch that many
- check we got enough, if we didn't repeat at most `LOOP` times, then give up and show what we got

In your case, we gave up. Sorry 'bout that! The "view more" link is shown only if we got enough data to populate the grid.

I'm going to rework that query to hopefully avoid this problem *and* avoid ever having to loop. And also to fix a corner case where we might not show the right numbers!

Answer (score -6):

This isn't a bug. That tab shows the posts on which you've gained reputation recently.

You see only 2 posts, meaning that there have been only two posts on which you've gained reputation recently. When you received an upvote, you get one more post, because that reputation is gained recently. This is quite common.

Many new users, who do not have reputation changes, see:

[image]

in their recent reputation tab.

To make it more simple, let's try a formula:

```
posts_shown = posts_on_which_reputation_gained_recently
```

Number or posts:

```
number_of_posts_shown = number_of_posts_on_which_reputation_gained_recently
```

In your case `posts_on_which_reputation_gained_recently` is 2. Thus, 2 posts are shown.

---

Also, I see this question as a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291910/new-activity-page-reputation-section-bug) one, once Cool Guy mentioned it. It solves your problem in the second para:

> Yours is really an edge case as your most recent events are all applicable to just the one post; you have 28 events for that one question but the 4 oldest are not included in the total reputation change. Those 4 events make up the remaining 17 points you earned for the post.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug. I have the code in front of me and I know what happened ;p